# #<String:0x0000555d5bddac58> (NoMethodError) in Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, ubuntu, containers

I have a project in Ruby on Rails framework, this project work well in a server (on premise), but when I put the code in a container does not work, the console show me the following error:

```bash
root@75815c97d5dc:/var/www/cenit# bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn_rails (/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/unicorn_rails)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        24: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
        23: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        22: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
        21: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in `with_friendly_errors'
        20: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
        19: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
        18: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
        17: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
        16: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        15: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        14: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        13: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli.rb:485:in `exec'
        12: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
        11: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
        10: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
         9: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
         8: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
         7: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
         6: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `new'
         5: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `initialize'
         4: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `new'
         3: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:68:in `initialize'
         2: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `reload'
         1: from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `instance_eval'
config/unicorn.rb:17:in `reload': undefined method `key?' for #<String:0x0000555d5bddac58> (NoMethodError)
```

the line 17 is:

```rb
preload_app config.key?('UNICORN_PRELOAD') ? config['UNICORN_PRELOAD'].to_b : true
```

the entire unicronr.rb:

```rb
# Set your full path to application.

app_dir = File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)
shared_dir = File.expand_path('../../../shared/', __FILE__)
app_name = "cenit"

# Set unicorn options
config =
  begin
    require 'psych'
    Psych.load(File.read("#{app_dir}/config/application.yml"))
  rescue
    {}
  end
listen 8080
worker_processes config['UNICORN_WORKERS'] || 5
preload_app config.key?('UNICORN_PRELOAD') ? config['UNICORN_PRELOAD'].to_b : true
timeout config['UNICORN_TIMEOUT'] || 240

GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

# Fill path to your app
working_directory app_dir

# Set up socket location
listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn.#{app_name}.sock", backlog: 64

# Loging
if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT']
  logger Logger.new(STDOUT)
else
  stderr_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.#{app_name}.stderr.log"
  stdout_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.#{app_name}.stdout.log"
end

# Set master PID location
pid "#{shared_dir}/pids/unicorn.#{app_name}.pid"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Cenit::Rabbit.close
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
  sleep 1
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  defined?(Rails) and Rails.cache.respond_to?(:reconnect) and Rails.cache.reconnect

  Cenit::Rabbit.init

  puts "Initializing Unicorn #{worker.nr}"

  if worker.nr.zero?
    puts "Initializing Unicorn Worker ZERO..."

    unless ENV['SKIP_DB_INITIALIZATION'].to_b
      Tenant.all.each do |tenant|
        tenant.switch do
          Setup::Scheduler.activated.each(&:start)
        end
      end
    end

    puts "Initializing scheduler..."

    scheduler = Cenit::Rabbit.start_scheduler
    data_sink = Cenit::Hook.start
    unless scheduler || data_sink
      Cenit::Rabbit.start_consumer
    end
  elsif worker.nr <= Cenit.maximum_unicorn_consumers
    puts "Starting consumer on Unicorn Worker..."
    Cenit::Rabbit.start_consumer
  end
end

before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{app_dir}/Gemfile"
end
```

application.yaml:

```yaml
MONGODB_URI: mongodb://localhost/cenit
UNICORN_WORKERS: 6
REDIS_HOST: localhost
BASE_MULTIPLIER_ACTIVE_TASKS: 50
SCHEDULER_LOOKUP_INTERVAL: 8
MAXIMUM_UNICORN_CONSUMERS: 6
UNICORN_CENIT_SERVER: true
MAXIMUM_UNICORN_CONSUMERS: 0
ENABLE_RERECAPTCHA: false
```

for now I will try using containers based in alpine and centos to verify that it is a debian-based container error

Comment: ...and show the contents of `config/application.yml`

Comment: it's done...I put the application.yml...!!!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I can't see any way that `config` would end up as a string.  Like you'd have to have a literal `""` in there or something (at the root level).

Comment: it is weird with official Ruby container does not work but if I install Ruby using RVM (in a clean container) work perfectly...look like if when I install Ruby using RVM,  it install some SO dependencies that solve this problem!!!

Comment: Very weird, but good that you have a workaround.